# Can a Visual Studio Code Workspace Be Used with Multiple Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to associate a workspace with multiple windows? For example, when I open a workspace, can I have it open memorized documents in two windows? If I open a new window from an existing workspace, will it be opened under the same workspace with the same extensions enabled and disabled?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To duplicate your workspace in a new window see [release notes, duplicate a workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_workbench).

> **Duplicate Workspace in New Window**
>
> There is a new command Duplicate Workspace in New Window to duplicate
>   the current workspace in a new window. This command can be used as a
>   workaround to the current limitation that one workspace cannot be
>   opened in two windows. The workaround works best when you have the
>   setting `files.autoSave` set to `afterDelay`, `onFocusChange`, or
>   `onWindowChange`. In this way, the editor documents will be synced
>   through the file system when you have the same document open in
>   different windows.

The new window will have the same extensions enabled and disabled.  But it will **not** open any files that you have already opened in the source window.  Pay heed to the above link's comments about **synchronizing your saves across windows**.

You will need to bind the command to a keybinding, for example:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+w",
  "command": "workbench.action.duplicateWorkspaceInNewWindow"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The information is very helpful. Would you also be able to have separate window layouts in these two windows, and could these be memorized when VS Code is closed and opened?

Comment: I've never done it before but it looks like if you save the duplicated workspace with a new name - it will prompt you when you close it - that you can then open both workspaces and it'll remember opened files  and sync saves across them.  I am mildly surprised by this and don't necessarily recommend this approach.  I did install an extension in one workspace and it showed up in the other.

Comment: Interesting! Appreciate the information and the time you spent investigating this feature.